# error using yum in centos 6

Tags: centos, yum

my yum command used to work fine , but now , when I try to use it ,

it gives me an error :

```
file:///home/user/repo/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14]
 Could not open/read file:///home/user/repo/repodata/repomd.xml
```

I don't know what to do , please help me.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /home/user/repo/repodata/repomd.xml`? I assume you are replacing your actual username with `user` right?

Comment: no , its weird for me too, there is no user directory under my /home directory .

Comment: and also there is no repo directory under my actual username directory @terdon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have one or more files in /etc/yum.repos.d/ that point to `file:///home/user/repo` as a basepath. Remove or correct those files and you should be okay.

Comment: this was exactly my problem, and it solved now , thank you very much